# How to pass twig variable to octobercms component

Tags: octobercms

Here is my code block, I want to pass the `service` variable to component.

```
{% for service in services %}
    <div data-service="#development" 
        class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" 
        data-wow-duration="300ms" 
        data-wow-delay="0ms"
    >
        <div class="media service-box">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                {% component 'editable' file={{ service }} %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.col-md-4-->
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Inside `{% .. %}` directives you can simply use twig variable names without the double curly braces `{{ .. }}` around them. The `{{ .. }}` braces just designate twig expressions wheras `{% .. %}` designates twig statements. See [twig templating documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html). Inside both twig variables can be simply accessed by their names.

So here you could just do like

```
{% component 'editable' file=service %}
```

Comment: This answer is more clear on what is going on. Good job!

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample from the code I'm using on Page element:

```
{% set shortDsc %}{{ details.shortDescription|raw }}{% endset %}
{% set productCode %}{{ details.productCode }}{% endset %}
{% set ContentID %}{{ calID }}{% endset %}
{% content ContentID 
           shortDesc = shortDsc
           prodCode = productCode
%}
```

... and then in Component just use variables as

```
{prodCode} {shortDesc}
```

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. The @trollkotze answer goes straight to the point of the question.